# How authenticate and search user in Active Directory using Spring Ldap

Tags: java, spring, spring-ldap

I wrote some java code using **javax.naming.directory** to authenticate a user in AD using ldap, that code working fine as I'm expecting. But the same code i need to implement using **Spring ldap** api. Any one can help on these.

To Initialize

```
private void setDefaultInitialContext() throws Exception
{
  LOG.debug("Setting default initail context");
  try
  {
    this.moLdapEnv.put(JAVA_NAMING_FACTORY_INITIAL, COM_SUN_JNDI_LDAP_LDAP_CTX_FACTORY);
    this.moLdapEnv.put(JAVA_NAMING_PROVIDER_URL, PropertiesReader.getLdapProperty(LDAP_URL) + ":" + PropertiesReader.getLdapProperty(LDAP_PORT));
    this.moLdapEnv.put(JAVA_NAMING_SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, PropertiesReader.getLdapProperty(LDAP_AUTHTYPE));
    this.moLdapEnv.put(JAVA_NAMING_SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, PropertiesReader.getLdapProperty(LDAP_BIND_USER_DN));
    this.moLdapEnv.put(JAVA_NAMING_SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, PropertiesReader.getLdapProperty(LDAP_PASSWORD));
    this.moLdapContext = new InitialDirContext(this.moLdapEnv);
    LOG.debug("Default initail context is set");
  } catch (Exception exception)
  {
    LOG.error("An Exception occurred LdapDao setting default initial context :" + exception.getMessage(), exception);
    throw exception;
  }
}
```

Authenticate:

```
public Boolean authenticate(String asUsername, String asUserPassword) throws Exception
{

  NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results = null;
  Boolean liAuthResult = Boolean.FALSE;
  try
  {
    setDefaultInitialContext();
    SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
    controls.setSearchScope(2);
    results = this.moLdapContext.search(PropertiesReader.getLdapProperty(LDAP_SEARCH_BASE_DN),
        "(&(objectclass=person)(sAMAccountName=" + asUsername + ")(memberOf=" + PropertiesReader.getLdapProperty(LDAP_GROUP_DN) + "))",
        controls);
    if (null != results && results.hasMore())
    {
      SearchResult searchResult = (SearchResult) results.next();
      if (null != searchResult)
      {
        moAttributes = searchResult.getAttributes();
        Attribute userDnAttr = moAttributes.get(DISTINGUISHED_NAME);
        String userDn = (String) userDnAttr.get();
        this.moLdapContext.close();
        this.moLdapEnv.put(JAVA_NAMING_SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userDn);
        this.moLdapEnv.put(JAVA_NAMING_SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, asUserPassword);
        this.moLdapEnv.put(COM_SUN_JNDI_LDAP_CONNECT_POOL, FALSE);
        this.moLdapContext = new InitialDirContext(this.moLdapEnv);
        liAuthResult = Boolean.TRUE;
      }
      LOG.debug("User Authenticated successfully");
    }
  } catch (NamingException exception)
  {
    throw exception;
  } catch (Exception exception)
  {
    throw exception;
  } finally
  {
    closeAllResources(results);
  }
  return liAuthResult;
}
```

Comment: did you look at this? http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/reference/#introduction

Comment: ya.. that is giving me more confusion..that i need to place where and all.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [separate chapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/reference/#user-authentication) on authentication in the Spring LDAP reference manual. If you have specific questions feel free to ask.

Please note that for authentication/authorization purposes you really should look into [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) (which in turn uses Spring LDAP under the covers).